Why does the Athansiadis-Linusson bijection encode floors?
The Athanasiadis-Linusson bijection is a correspondence between dominant regions of the $k$-Shi arrangement (in type A) and $k$-parking functions. I'll take $k=1$ here for convenience here.
Let $V$ be the subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ whose entries sum to 0, and consider the hyperplanes $H_{x_{i}-x_{j},m}$ of points with $x_{i}-x_{j} = m$, for $i < j$ and $m = 0,1$. The connected components of complement of the union of these hyperplanes are the regions of the Shi arrangement. The dominant regions are those where $x_{i}-x_{j} > 0$ for all $i<j$.
The correspondence is basically this - start with the sequence $1,2,\ldots,n$. A chamber of the Shi arrangement is determined by the inequalities $x_{i}-x_{j} > m$ which are true on the entire chamber. If $x_{i}-x_{j} > 1$ on a chamber, we connect $i$ and $j$ with an arc. After all such arcs are drawn, we delete any arc which completely contains another. Then the parking function $f$ for the region assigns $f(x)$ to be the position of the leftmost element connected to x via arcs.
For example, in this picture (from the original paper), the region labelled 113 has $x_{1}-x_{2} > 1$, and $x_{1}-x_{3} > 1$. So we would draw arcs from 1 to 2, and 1 to 3. But since the arc from 1 to 3 contains the other one, it is deleted. Then the arc diagram is essentially the set partition $\{\{1,2\},\{3\}\}$, so $f(1)=f(2) = 1$ and $f(3) = 3$ - denoted 113 here.

So, intuitively, I understand what's happening here - we are interested in the "floors'' of the region - hyperplanes that separate the region from the origin and form part of its boundary. If $x_{1}-x_{2} > 1$ and $x_{2}-x_{3} > 0$, then it is automatic that $x_{1}-x_{3} > 1$, so this is extraneous information and we delete the arc. But geometrically, this is also capturing the fact that while the hyperplane $x_{1}-x_{3} = 1$ separates this region from the origin, it is not a "floor'' of the region since only one point of it is on the boundary of the region. I have seen references elsewhere in the literature casually mentioning that this bijection is encoding floors, but I haven't seen a proof.
So my question is, what is the best way to show that the conditions that cause us to delete an arc actually cause the corresponding hyperplane to not be a floor of the region? For this region, you can argue that the points in its closure where $x_{1}-x_{3} = 1$ are a subset of $H_{x_{1}-x_{2},1} \cap H_{x_{2}-x_{3},0}$, and thus have codimension at least 2. Similar arguments work in general, but it doesn't feel very satisfying. Is there standard proof of this somewhere out there? Thanks for any pointers!

Ok, a couple more days of work and I've found an answer. The pieces are all in Shi's original work, but Athansiadis puts it all together in "On a refinement of the generalized Catalan numbers for Weyl groups". (Or at least, that's what finally made me understand it.)
Shi characterizes the regions of the arrangement as follows. For a region $R$ and a positive root $\alpha$, let $k_{\alpha}(R)$ be the integer $k$ so that $R$ lies between $H_{\alpha,k}$ and $H_{\alpha,k+1}$. Then whenever $\alpha + \beta$ is also a positive root, $k_{\alpha} + k_{\beta} \leq k_{\alpha+\beta} \leq k_{\alpha} + k_{\beta} + 1$. This is a biconditional - if you choose $k_{\alpha}$ satisfying that property, then there is an alcove with those coordinates.
So, in my example, the minimal alcove has coordinates $k_{\alpha_{1}} = 1$, $k_{\alpha_{2}} = 0$, and $k_{\theta} = 1$. If $k_{\theta}$ were a floor of that alcove, then we could cross over that facet and only that facet, to get to an alcove with the same coordinates except that now $k_{\theta} = 0$. However, that violates the given condition. So any time that $k_{\alpha + \beta} = k_{\alpha} + k_{\beta}$, this means $H_{\alpha + \beta,k}$ cannot actually be a floor of the region - this is essentially what my codimension argument was saying, that there is not enough flexibility in that alcove boundary to support an entire facet. I don't know if that version of the argument is satisfying to everyone - Shi's result comes from some slightly intricate calculations on inner products and $W_{a}$ acting on roots, etc., but it feels a bit better to me.
